# Jobs spark failure

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I want to launch a spark job on R I get this error :

```
Erreur : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:82) ....
```

In spark logs (/opt/mapr/spark/spark-version/logs) I find a lot of theses exceptions :

```
ERROR FsHistoryProvider: Exception encountered when attempting to load application log maprfs:///apps/spark/.60135a9b-ec7c-4f71-8f92-4d4d2fbb1e2b
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File maprfs:///apps/spark/.60135a9b-ec7c-4f71-8f92-4d4d2fbb1e2b does not exist.
```

Any idea how could I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create sparkContext (or get if it exists)

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

// 1. Create Spark configuration
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("SparkMe Application")
  .setMaster("local[*]")  // local mode

// 2. Create Spark context
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

or

```
SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thank you Yehor.
In fact my Spark Context is already created in my R code : :

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),"R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(devtools)
library(magrittr)
library(SparkR)
library(devtools)
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(DBI)
# Spark context creation
slyr <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = list())